# How the page should behave after applying filters?

Tags: e-commerce, filter, faceted-search

I'm working on the e-commerce website with facet filters, when user applies the filters, results appear (no need to click additional "show results button") but I'm not sure how the page should behave:

**Reload and scroll to the top** - if user would like to apply a lot of filters, he need to scroll down every time he chooses one filter to apply another, e.g. http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Laptop-Computers/PC-Laptops/pcmcat247400050000.c?id=pcmcat247400050000

**Reload but stays at the same position, page doesn't scroll top** - it's a good solution for users who would like to apply more filters, e.g. http://www.target.com/c/laptops-computers-tablets-electronics/-/N-5xtf4#?lnk=lnav_shop categories_6

Answer (score 2):

I think "reload and scroll to the top" is better solution, as:

- scrolling to the top is clear indicator of the page was changed
- there are some display options above the items (sorting, view style, etc.) which could be applied. A scenario could be: 1) filter laptops by screen size 2) order them by price. Without auto scrolling user should scroll to the top manually to set the options
- without scrolling to top user often sees partial content (bottom fragment of previous row and top fragment of next row), so he is not able to perceive the whole items immediately after filtering

You could also improve the filtering implementation. Place more frequent filter options separately and link "Other filters", which popups dialog containing all the filters. This dialog allows to set several filters at once, avoiding multiple page reloads, which are annoying.

Look at eBay implementation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm still little bit worried how more advanced users who would like to apply more filters at once will perceive this top auto scrolling solution. They could be annoyed I guess, auto scrolling is perfect for users who choose one or two filters and this is sufficient form them.

Comment: Another nice argument for scrolling page up is that if user applied a lot filters and list of them is long and there are only e.g. 5 results he won't see results cause they'll appear at the top of the page while filters are at the bottom.